# Python monitor progress of multipart form upload

Tags: python, http, python-requests, progress-bar, multipartform-data

I've been trying for a while to implement monitoring the progress of a POST request using `requests`. I've tried using the `MultipartEncoder` strategy using `requests-toolbelt` and other's using chunking but unfortunately it only works for requests with `data=` payloads and not `file=` payloads. The site Im using returns a 400 if I try any `data` payloads. The API can be seen here: https://file.io
The headers do not support chunking either. I really need a progress bar for the UI of my application. They have a working progress bar on their site, but I'm really struggling to understand their JS.

```
class FileDeliveryHandler:

    def __init__(self, url='https://file.io'):
        self.post_url = url

    def post_file_to_api(self, path_to_file):
        file = {'file': (path_to_file, open(path_to_file, 'rb'))}
        r = requests.post(self.post_url, files={'file': file})

        return r.text
```

Comment: Create a generator which reads file in chunks

Comment: Passing a generator to `requests.post` is forbidden from what I know

Comment: It is not. 
https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests